# Как конвертировать строку в дату?

Tags: python, парсер, дата, datetime, формат

Пытаюсь конвертировать дату:

```
Wed, 06 Jan 2021 12:56:00 +0200
```

в дату python, однако получаю ошибку.

> re.error: redefinition of group name 'b' as group 8; was group 3 at position 211

Код

```
date_time_str = 'Wed, 06 Jan 2021 12:56:00 +0200'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%a,/%m %b /%y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

Подскажите, как конвертировать такой формат даты?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы указали неправильный формат.

Попробуйте так:

```
In [106]: datetime.strptime('Wed, 06 Jan 2021 12:56:00 +0200', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
Out[106]: datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 6, 12, 56, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)))
```

Общий тактический совет - если не уверены как правильно задать весь формат целиком, делайте это пошагово - так легче локализировать ошибку:

```
In [107]: datetime.strptime('Wed, 06 Jan', '%a, %d %b')
Out[107]: datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 6, 0, 0)

In [108]: datetime.strptime('Wed, 06 Jan 2021 12:56:00', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
Out[108]: datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 6, 12, 56)

In [109]: datetime.strptime('Wed, 06 Jan 2021 12:56:00 +0200', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
Out[109]: datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 6, 12, 56, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Внимательнее с символами формата, [подробнее тут](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.strptime('Wed, 06 Jan 2021 12:56:00 +0200', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'))
```